# MvcSiteMapProvider issue when set route values for node with securityTrimmingEnabled is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have project with win auth and i use "securityTrimmingEnabled" option for detect to which parts of menu user have access.

I set site map node properties:

```
siteMapNode.ParentNode.Title = entity.Parent.Title;
siteMapNode.ParentNode.RouteValues["id"] = entity.Parent.Id;
```

And if "securityTrimmingEnabled" is false, everything is ok and i have correct url in map path(/portfolios/facility/57), if "securityTrimmingEnabled" is true, title of node is ok, but "id" param is not correct(/portfolios/facility/0)

How i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same issue [described here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/272).

The AuthorizeAttributeAclModule is accessing the Url property and causing it to be request cached, so setting properties that affect the URL afterward (such as in a controller action) has no effect.

**Option 1**

Move the code that sets the RouteValues["id"] into a [IDynamicNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) implemenation. This will load the values into the shared cache at application startup (and when the cache expires), but it also loads them before the AuthorizeAttributeAclModule fires.

**Option 2**

Move the code that sets the values into the Application_BeginRequest event as described [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/272#issuecomment-34546421).

**Option 3**

Create a custom implementation of [RequestCacheableSiteMapNode](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/RequestCacheableSiteMapNode.cs) that doesn't override the Url property and a custom [SiteMapNodeFactory](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/SiteMapNodeFactory.cs) to provide instances of your new class, then inject them both with DI.

**Option 4**

Remove the request cache value for the Url property manually, so it can be regenerated the next time the Url property is accessed.

```
var parentNode = siteMapNode.ParentNode;

parentNode.Title = entity.Parent.Title;
parentNode.RouteValues["id"] = entity.Parent.Id; 

var urlRequestCacheKey = "__MVCSITEMAPNODE_" + parentNode.SiteMap.CacheKey + "_" + parentNode.Key + "_Url_True_";
this.HttpContext.Items.Remove(urlRequestCacheKey);
```